# Docusaurus: Markdown links not working with .mdx files for inter-page linking

Tags: markdown, mdx, docusaurus

I'm building a documentation website using Docusaurus and facing an issue with markdown links specifically when using `.mdx` files for inter-page linking. Surprisingly, the markdown content itself renders correctly within `.mdx` files, but the links within those files fail to work as expected.

Strangely, the markdown links function perfectly fine when using regular `.md` files. However, when I switch to `.mdx` files, the links no longer work despite ensuring proper configuration updates.

I have attempted various approaches for markdown links, including URL paths and file paths. Furthermore, I have updated the Docusaurus configuration to include `.mdx` files (what is most likely obsolete).

During the build process, I receive the following error message related to broken links:

```
#0 43.80 [ERROR] Unable to build website for locale en.
#0 43.80 [ERROR] Error: Docusaurus found broken links!
#0 43.80 
#0 43.80 Please check the pages of your site in the list below, and make sure you don't reference any path that does not exist.
#0 43.80 Note: it's possible to ignore broken links with the 'onBrokenLinks' Docusaurus configuration, and let the build pass.
#0 43.80 
#0 43.80 Exhaustive list of all broken links found:
#0 43.80 
#0 43.80 - On source page path = /en/docs/advanced/getting_started_robot_framework:
#0 43.80    -> linking to ../intermediate/01_create_project.mdx (resolved as: /en/docs/intermediate/01_create_project.mdx)
```

I find it puzzling that the [official documentation](https://docusaurus.io/docs/markdown-features/links) refers to using .mdx files, implying that they should support markdown links. However, despite extensive efforts, I have been unable to resolve this issue.

If anyone has encountered a similar problem or has suggestions on how to enable markdown links within `.mdx` files for inter-page linking, I would be immensely grateful for your guidance. Thank you in advance for any insights or recommendations!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue. I dropped the `.mdx` suffix in the link and it worked. See if it works for you if you link to `../intermediate/01_create_project` instead of to `../intermediate/01_create_project.mdx`.